# How to write unit testcases for ElectronJs app using Jest Framweork?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, electron, spectron

I am trying to write unit test cases on window, ipcMain, and similar functionalities for Electron App using Jest. Can anyone guide how to proceed?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help without seeing the code you want to test

Comment: @Sushma are you talking about packed Electron applications, I mean by installable applications by this question, right ?